# Programmatically suspend/resume a JVM

Tags: java, jvm

I have a "main" java application that will start another java applications each one on its own JVM. The "main" application will, eventually, suspend, resume, or kill the other applications. Restriction: if the "main" application dies, the other applications must still run.

How to do that?

I've used JDI (java debugger interface) but if the "main" application ends, the other applications are stopped also.

Comment: This sounds like a strange design.

Comment: @coolbeans: not too strange, if you think on debuggers or applications like the Java VisualVM

Comment: true, that's a valid use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The only way I see is, as you say, to use JDI. But instead of using "local debug", you can try to use "remote debug" (debugging the child JVMs through a TCP port). This should avoid the children JVM stopping even if the main JVM dies.

Comment: hi @edutesoy: currently i'm doing something like:

`LaunchingConnector connector = findLaunchingConnector();
 Map arguments = connectorArguments(connector, mainArgs);
 VirtualMachine vm = connector.launch(arguments);`

an then I use vm to suspend/resume.

How can switch that into a "remote debug" ? I need to use other kind of connector?

tnx

Comment: I don't know the internals of JDI, but i know that it is possible because the IDEs like Eclipse are able to debug a remote JVM through TCP/IP, and when the IDE dies, the remote application keeps working. And you can reconnect again to suspend it or whatever.

Comment: Isn't it problematic of you attach a debugger, suspend at least one thread with a breakpoint and then the debugging application crashes before resuming the debugged application? Wouldn't the suspended threads still be suspended in the debugged application?

Comment: Nop, if the "debugger" crashes, the suspended thread is resumed. No zombies in JDI.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just write the other applications to open a `ServerSocket` and accept commands over it? It would be easy enough to set up a simple command processor that understands "suspend", "resume", and "kill". The child could choose a random port to listen on, and print the port number when it starts, so the parent could easily get that information, then contact the child via a TCP connection.

Comment: The problem that I see with this is that the thread that receives this "command" would not be able to "suspend" other threads...

Comment: Hi @ernest: I'm not the developper of the other applications. In theory, the "main" application can be asked to start any java application.

Comment: @edutesoy: sure it could, if the other threads were watching for a global "suspended" flag to be set.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using [Runtime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) to issue commands to launch your other applications(just like going to the CLI and issuing a java something.jar command.

Then also use the same thing to kill the other applications you launched but you probably need to get hold of their process id(pid) maybe using [this](http://blog.igorminar.com/2007/03/how-java-application-can-discover-its.html)

Comment: hi @Hyangelo: yes as you say I can use runtime to launch other applications but then I have no way to keep a hand on these apps in order to suspend/resume them. The Process interface is very poor.

Comment: Yes you can, as I said in my answer you're going to have to do a taskkill command using the PID.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you're talking about a multi-threaded application.  The obvious solution would be to subclass the threads and embed the ability to set flags in the thread.

```
public void run() {
  while (keepRunning && notSuspended) {
     doNextItem(...);
  }
  while (notSuspended == false) {
     try {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       // do nothing but continue
     }
  }
}

public void suspend() {
  notSuspended = false;
}

public void resume() {
  notSuspended = true;
}

public void kill() {
  keepRunning = false;
}
```

Other solutions that capture the thread from within the internals of the JVM are possible (like using the JDI interface); however, it is not really feasible to design code to maintain a consistent state when the threads are being interfered with externally.  A design that internalizes the resting of the thread in a consistent state is much preferred if you want to actually verify that the program state is correctly consistent after a thread was paused.

Comment: hi @edwin: I'm not working with independent threads but with independent JVM instances